# Does "having" something imply the possession of it?

Tags: verbs, connotation

I'm seriously pained when I hear the word "have" being used in the present continuous to imply possession.

Take for example, the following quotation from [Wordsmith.org](http://wordsmith.org/words/fulsome.html).

> Read the Etymology of the word "fulsome", which has been described as "...-some (**having** a particular quality).

Grammar books have always suggested that this construction implies "eating, consuming, or experiencing"; **never** possession. So, if I said that I'm "having a friend", that  would imply that I'm eating the friend, or having sex with her/him.

What do you folks think?

Answer (score 5):

There's a difference between the present continuous ("to be" + present participle in "-ing"), and other uses of the present participle.

So, in your example:

> ...-some (having a particular quality)

there is no "to be", so this is a use of the participle as an adjective, not a present continuous. It is equivalent to saying:

> ...-some (*that have* a particular quality)

You are correct that using the present continuous here

> *that are having a particular quality

would be inappropriate.

Similarly, in your "friend" example, you are right that saying

> I'm having a friend

that could have a number of meanings(!), but not that the person in question simply is your friend - but, on the other hand, saying

> People having friends in America knew more about the issues surrounding the president.

is fine, and equivalent to

> People that had friends in America knew more about the issues surrounding the president.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could certainly use "having" to mean possession. Consider:

> I got so used to having a car that I was unprepared for how arduous it was to walk to work every day.

or

> Having 500 friends on FaceBook isn't as good as having two actual friends in real life.

or

> What does having high cholesterol suggest about a person's dietary habits?

Answer (score 0):

In American English, I can say all of the following without being misunderstood by other native speakers:

1. "I have two cats." (ownership)
2. "She has several friends." (Not exactly ownership, but close)
3. "I have a cold." (experience)
4. "We have pizza on Friday nights." (consume)
5. "He has a beard." (ownership)

Numbers 1 and 4 would never be mistaken by a native speaker to mean anything other than possession. Context, however, does make a difference. If I were to say, "I had several women last night" that would definitely imply sex.

Comment: "I have two cats" isn't ownership.  At least if you ask the cats (or any "owner" of a cat)  ;-)

Comment: @ SSAKL: While I'm still seeping in the comments of the others (and getting educated in the process), the issue is not with using "have/has" in any other tense apart from the present continuous (i.e. "-ing")

Comment: @jae - It is in my neck of the woods. American English, native speaker. The British (and various legal systems) probably make more of a distinction.

Comment: @Dhruv Rah Sharma - I see that now. I was attempting to give a general answer to a more specific question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

"Have" always doesn't mean "possession", but in many cases it does. For eg.:

### "Have" as a transitive verb

1. to hold in the hand or in control; own; possess: *to have wealth*
2. to possess or contain as a part, characteristic, attribute, etc.: *she has blue eyes; the week has seven days*
3. to be affected by or afflicted with: *to have a cold*
4. to possess by way of experience; experience; undergo: *have a good time*
5. to possess an understanding of; know: *to have only a little Spanish*
6. to hold or keep in the mind: *to have an idea*
7. to declare or state: *so gossip has it*
8. to gain possession, control, or mastery of; *I have been trained in Classical Music*
9. (a) to get, take, receive, or obtain: *to have news of someone, have a look at it*                                                                    (b) to consume; eat or drink: *have some tea*
10. to bear or beget (offspring)
11. to perform; carry on; engage in: *to have an argument*
12. to cause to: *have them walk home*
13. to cause to be: *have this done first*
14. to be in a certain relation to: *to have brothers and sisters*
15. to feel and show: *have pity on her*
16. to permit; tolerate: used in the negative: *I won't have this nonsense*

### "Have" used in an informal way

1. to hold at a disadvantage or to overcome: *I had my opponent now*
2. to deceive; take in; cheat: *they were had in that business deal*
3. to engage in sexual intercourse with

### As a noun

1. a person or nation with relatively much wealth or rich resources: *the haves and have-nots.*